# WordPress login page error message customize and relocate

Tags: wordpress, validation, authentication

I have wordpress error mesages comming from wp-includes/user.php.

I have a customized Log in page(TML). I want to place the error messages after the input Fields.

At present they are validated and coming at the top of the from. I want to place the error message($template->the_errors(); ) after input fields(email and password accordingly).

```
<div id="signInPage">
    <div id="blackSignInBox">
        <h1>ONBoard Guide Sign-In</h1>
        <!-- <p id="message">Enter your email addres and password provided</p> -->
        <h2 id="mobileh1signin">ONBoard Guide<br /> Sign-In</h2>
        <div class="tml tml-login" id="theme-my-login<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>">
            <?php $template->the_action_template_message( 'login' ); ?>
            <?php $template->the_errors(); ?>
            <form name="loginform"  id="loginform<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" action="<?php $template->the_action_url( 'login', 'login_post' ); ?>" method="post">
            <span class="input-wrap email sipage">
                <label for="user_login<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Email', 'theme-my-login' ); ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'log' ); ?>" size="20" />
                <div class="error email-error">You have entered an invalid email. Try again.</div>
            </span>

            <span id="passSI" class="input-wrap password sipage">
                <label for="user_pass<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Password', 'theme-my-login' ); ?></label>
                <div id="inputContainer">
                    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="" size="20" autocomplete="off" />
                    <button type="button" id="showHide" onclick="passFunction()">Show </button>
                </div>  
                <div class="error password-error">Please enter a password</div>
                <p class="action-link lost-password"><?php $template->lost_pw_action_link(); ?></p>

            </span>

            <?php do_action( 'login_form' ); ?>

            <span class="tml-submit-wrap sipage">
                <button type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" ><?php esc_attr_e( 'Sign In', 'theme-my-login' ); ?></button>
                <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php $template->the_redirect_url( 'login' ); ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="instance" value="<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login" />
            </span>

            </form>
    <p class="action-link register">Don't have an account? <?php $template->register_action_link(); ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form ?

Comment: Also, here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_errors